# what is the advantage of using Hamilton dynamics in sampling methods?

Tags: sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, gradient, hamiltonian-monte-carlo

I am wondering apart form being gradient based sampling methods, what is the advantages of using Hamiltonian MCMC?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_Monte_Carlo ?

Comment: yes, I saw that, but in concert I would like to know, which kind of properties make them as privilege to be used.

Comment: "Compared to using a Gaussian random walk proposal distribution in the Metropolis–Hastings algorithm, Hamiltonian Monte Carlo reduces the correlation between successive sampled states by proposing moves to distant states which maintain a high probability of acceptance"

Comment: i.e. more data efficient for some distributions

Comment: The MH sampling proposes new samples based on a proposal distribution. It proposes new samples in a random way, so your next sample can be close to your previous iteration. On the other hand in the Hamiltonian sampling process, there is the use of LeapFrog integration where it "jumps" (in a deterministic way) into areas "sufficiently" further away from your previous iteration.

Comment: Some of these also seem relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=hamiltonian